# Is there any performance overhead in using RaiseEvent in .NET?

Tags: performance, compact-framework, raiseevent

Is there any performance overhead in using RaiseEvent in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)?

I have a code which is similar to following.

```
Dim _startTick As Integer = Environment.TickCount
'Do some Task'
Dim duration As Integer = Environment.TickCount - _startTick
Logger.Debug("Time taken: {0}", duration)
RaiseEvent Datareceived()
```

The above code returns:

```
Time taken: 1200

Time taken: 1400
```

But if I remove `RaiseEvent` it returns:

```
Time taken: 110

Time taken: 121
```

I am surprised that the `RaiseEvent` is called after the logging of time taken. How does it affect the total time taken?

I am working on [.NET Compact Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Compact_Framework).

In the Eventhandler I had given a MsgBox. When I removed the message box, it is now showing time taken as 110, 121, etc., that is, less that 500 milliseconds. If I put the Msgbox back in eventhandler it shows 1200, 1400, etc., that is, more than a second.

I am more surprised now (the event is raised after the logging part).

Comment: Maybe the `RaiseEvent` is the only statement that does anything with the received data, so if you remove it, (part of) the computation is optimized away?

Comment: Event handler of this Raised event just shows a Msgbox. Further update if I remove the Msgbox and put Logger.Debug performance is improved. The main point is RaiseEvent is called after the logging then how it effects something that is already executed.

Comment: It shouldn't be affecting previously executed code. As Time Taken is over 1 second, you might want to try step through the 'Some task' to see if there's any operation there taking all that time.

Comment: @deltreme : It is the only code shown above. No 'some task' is done.
I am more surprised for the same that it is affecting previously executed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the same in a console application. A console application uses fewer resources.

Here you can identify the exact issue.

Comment: Thanks. was too involved in issue. never thought of this simple method.